# Speed Up KNN and Maintaining Accuracy for Anomaly Detection

Tags: outliers, k-nearest-neighbour, anomaly-detection, subsampling

This question is about using KNN in the context of anomaly detection. If the training dataset is large(10 M data points), KNN will be slow. Is subsampling(i.e. use a small subset of original training set, e.g. 10K) a viable way to reduce time complexity? But when using subsampling, different samples will lead to very different results. How to obtain more stable results?

Comment: anomaly by nature happens rarely, subsampling should be done with care. why do you use knn?

Comment: What other methods do you suggest? My dataset is very similar to the one used in this blog(https://towardsdatascience.com/anomaly-detection-for-dummies-15f148e559c1). It also shows KNN produces a better result than other methods.

Comment: why would subsampling lead to very different results? that indicates that your dataset is not in fact that big

Comment: Can you describe your dataset. What kind of data domain, number of features, datatypes features etc?

Answer (score 0):

The issue of large storage requirements for KNN can be addressed by storing only "prototype" samples and using these during the Nearest Neighbour lookup process. Some widely cited paper reviewing such techniques are [A Taxonomy and Experimental Study on Prototype Generation for Nearest Neighbor Classification](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5709998) and [Prototype Selection for Nearest Neighbor Classification: Taxonomy and Empirical Study](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6136515).

Unfortunately there are not many good open-source implementations of these techniques. One Python library is [scikit-protopy](https://github.com/dvro/scikit-protopy), but it has not been updated since 2015.